# PS3 with select displaying menu wrongly

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm scripting a small program for my company and I'm using `PS3` and `select` to display the menu, the problem is that instead of printing a menu like this one:

```
1. SharePoint
2. AWS
3. Connect Direct
4. Proofpoint
5. DELL
6. Sair
```

The program prints it like this:

```
1. SharePoint   3. Connect Direct   5. DELL
2. AWS          4. Proofpoint       6. Sair
```

Here's the code:

```
function postagem(){
    clear
    quodZip
    PS3="Plataforma que deseja enviar o arquivo [1-5]: "
    select i in 'SharePoint' 'AWS' 'Connect Direct' 'Proofpoint' 'DELL' 'Sair'
    do
        case "$i" in
                "SharePoint")
                plataforma="Share Point";
                break
                ;;
            
            "AWS")
                plataforma="AWS";
                break
                ;;

            "Connect Direct")
                plataforma="Connect Direct";
                break
                ;;

            "Proofpoint")
                plataforma="Proofpoint";
                break
                ;;

            "DELL")
                plataforma="DELL";
                break
                ;;

            "Sair")
                exit;
                ;;
            
            *)
                echo ''
                echo "Opcao invalida, escolha novamente"
                ;;
            esac
    done
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the COLUMNS variable before select.

```
function postagem(){
    COLUMNS=0
    clear
    quodZip
    PS3="Plataforma que deseja enviar o arquivo [1-5]: "
    select i in 'SharePoint' 'AWS' 'Connect Direct' 'Proofpoint' 'DELL' 'Sair'
    do
        case "$i" in
                "SharePoint")
                plataforma="Share Point";
                break
                ;;
            
            "AWS")
                plataforma="AWS";
                break
                ;;

            "Connect Direct")
                plataforma="Connect Direct";
                break
                ;;

            "Proofpoint")
                plataforma="Proofpoint";
                break
                ;;

            "DELL")
                plataforma="DELL";
                break
                ;;

            "Sair")
                exit;
                ;;
            
            *)
                echo ''
                echo "Opcao invalida, escolha novamente"
                ;;
            esac
    done
}
```